# multilevel menu is not displaying

Tags: jquery, menu, submenu

i have this example here http://jsfiddle.net/65R8q/2/ for a multilevel submenu but it's not showing up because of using stop() to make the first sub menu steady how to fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".cat").mouseover(function () {
        $(".sub1").slideDown(500, function () {
            $(this).css("display", "block");
        });
    });

    $(".cat").mouseout(function () {
        $(".sub1").slideUp(500, function () {
            $(this).css("display", "none");
        });
    });

    $(".sub1").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css("display", "block").stop();
    });

    $(".sub1").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).slideUp(500, function () {
            $(this).css("display", "none");
        });
    });

    $(".item2").mouseover(function () {
        $(".sub2").slideDown(500, function () {
            $(this).css("display", "block");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cleared lots of css mistakes and lots of jQuery conflicts. At last i've manage to work this thing out.

[**Here is jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/65R8q/31/)

**First** of all you don't need to use callback function which manipulates css `display: block/none` after `slideUp/slideDown` because these methods automaticly `hides/shows $(this)` element after complete.

**Second:** You should select wrapper element for triggering nav. In your example you choose small element `.cat`, this is wrong. You should select biggest ele which wraps whole navigation. In your example: `.menu`

**Third:** Don't forgot to define `top:0; left:0;` when `position` protert used. If you don't define top/left values, it will create conflict on some browsers.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu').bind({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(".sub1").stop(true,false).slideDown(500);
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(".sub1").slideUp(500);
        }
    });

    $('.item2').bind({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(".sub2").stop(true,false).slideDown(500);
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(".sub2").slideUp(500);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for helping but menu contains multiple items not only one check this please http://jsfiddle.net/65R8q/32/ and i want the submenu to display when hovering over the categories link not the whole menu div

Comment: Than you need to create an element which wraps trigger elements, otherwise it will create a conflict. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/65R8q/34/